# Make a timeseries with text as values - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

If I have column A with lots of dates, and column B with 10 different texts (for example ‘apple’, ‘banana’, ‘orange’, etc..)that repeat and vary many times for all the rows in the dataset.. how can I identify based on a dataseries whats the count for each one of the words, per date? I could maybe group by year or month and ideally make a line plot, but im having trouble putting this together.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for count values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['2010-10-02','2011-09-11','2011-12-18','2022-02-08','2022-09-24'],
                   'B':['banana','banana','orange','orange','orange']})
print (df)
            A       B
0  2010-10-02  banana
1  2011-09-11  banana
2  2011-12-18  orange
3  2022-02-08  orange
4  2022-09-24  orange
```

---

```
df.A = pd.to_datetime(df.A)
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.A.dt.year, df.B)
print (df1)
B     banana  orange
A                   
2010       1       0
2011       1       1
2022       0       2

df1 = pd.crosstab(df.A.dt.month, df.B)
print (df1)
B   banana  orange
A                 
2        0       1
9        1       1
10       1       0
12       0       1


df1 = pd.crosstab(df.A.dt.to_period('m'), df.B)
print (df1)
B        banana  orange
A                      
2010-10       1       0
2011-09       1       0
2011-12       0       1
2022-02       0       1
2022-09       0       1
```

Last ploting:

```
df1.plot()
```

Comment: I love you! Thanks so much, really appreciate it.